# Overlapping scrollbar in tkinter gui

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I have a double scrollbar frame in a GUI based on tkinter but the right side of the horizontal scrollbar overlaps with the vertical bar and the right arrow is not visible.

I primarily used the code from the following link https://lucasg.github.io/2015/07/21/How-to-make-a-proper-double-scrollbar-frame-in-Tkinter/

As can be seen from the image in the figure on the bottom right the two scrollbars are overlapping and the right arrow of horizontal scrollbar is not visible.

Copying the code from the link mentioned as it serves as a minimal  reproducible example

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class DoubleScrollbarFrame(ttk.Frame):

  def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
    '''
      Initialisation. The DoubleScrollbarFrame consist of :
        - an horizontal scrollbar
        - a  vertical   scrollbar
        - a canvas in which the user can place sub-elements
    '''

    ttk.Frame.__init__(self,  master, **kwargs)

    # Canvas creation with double scrollbar
    self.hscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient = tk.HORIZONTAL)
    self.vscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient = tk.VERTICAL)
    self.sizegrip = ttk.Sizegrip(self)
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, 
                                  yscrollcommand = self.vscrollbar.set,
                                  xscrollcommand = self.hscrollbar.set)
    self.vscrollbar.config(command = self.canvas.yview)
    self.hscrollbar.config(command = self.canvas.xview)

  def pack(self, **kwargs):
    '''
      Pack the scrollbar and canvas correctly in order to recreate the same look as MFC's windows. 
    '''

    self.hscrollbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X, expand=tk.FALSE)
    self.vscrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y,  expand=tk.FALSE)
        self.sizegrip.pack(in_ = self.hscrollbar, side = tk.BOTTOM, anchor = "se")
    self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5,
                                             fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)

    ttk.Frame.pack(self, **kwargs)



  def get_frame(self):
    '''
      Return the "frame" useful to place inner controls.
    '''
    return self.canvas


if __name__ == '__main__':

  # Top-level frame
  root = tk.Tk()
  root.title( "Double scrollbar with tkinter" )
  root.minsize(width = 600, height = 600)
  frame = DoubleScrollbarFrame(root, relief="sunken")

  # Add controls here
  subframe = ttk.Frame( frame.get_frame() ) 
  txt = ttk.Label(subframe, text="Add things here !")

  #Packing everything
  txt.pack(anchor = 'center', fill = tk.Y, expand = tk.Y)
  subframe.pack(padx  = 15, pady   = 15, fill = tk.BOTH, expand = tk.TRUE)
  frame.pack( padx   = 5, pady   = 5, expand = True, fill = tk.BOTH)


  # launch the GUI
  root.mainloop()
```

I want to know how can I modify the code so that I can see the right side of the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: You need to use `grid()` instead of `pack()`. You can steal from [my code](https://gist.github.com/novel-yet-trivial/2841b7b640bba48928200ff979204115) to do this. As a bonus my code has a working mousewheel on all OSes.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess I will update my code based on your example @Novel.

Comment: The right side of your horizontal scrollbar is hidden because the sizegrip widget is packed there. If you pack sizegrip as `self.sizegrip.pack(side = tk.BOTTOM, anchor = "se")` then it works fine.